# Error when using instance property from static method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this TypeScript class:

```
export class UserCredentials {
  public name: string;

  static getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

When I remove the `static` everything works fine. But with it, I have the following compiler error : `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof UserCredentials'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In static method you cant access "this" instance or its properties.
Mark your field with "static" modifier to make it work:

```
public static name: string;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situations you must only (if you don't want make property 'name' static) create new instance inside static method

```
export class UserCredentials {
    public name: string;

    static getName() {
        const userCredentials = new UserCredentials(); // <--- create this
        return userCredentials.name;
    }
}
```